# Is there any way to check whether form is dirty or not in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-grid, kendo-validator

I have one form validator example in java script. In this case, Is there any way to check whether the form is dirty or not?

My platform is JavaScript

Please find corresponding sample below, and suggest any solution.

[sample link](https://dojo.telerik.com/APiVoMEl)

code snipet:
i have used like:

```js
if (name.value != name.defaultValue) { 
    alert("#name has changed"); 
    }
```

Comment: What is the issue are you facing

Comment: I want to check whether form is dirty or not. if the the form is dirty it has to show some popup. is ther any way to check this in javascript.

Comment: @SumeshTG, in angular they have dirty variable which shows whether form is dirty or not. but i want to check this in javascript

Comment: What do you mean, when you say 'dirty'?

Comment: if  any one of the form element has been touched or changed then the form is dirty

Comment: @PoulBak, check this link https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_validation.asp

Comment: Use jquery validator.

Comment: @SumeshTG, how can i do it

Comment: @kumaresan_sd Refer https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/ . Share your form  will help you to implement

Comment: @SumeshTG, check this sample. i need like this. if you change input and them submit it show some message which show fomr dirty https://stackblitz.com/edit/m4tbav-d5xcfq?file=index.js

Comment: Plz incluide your code snippet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have tags as kendo-ui-grid and kendo-validator so I suppose you are using kendo framework.
if you want to see if the form is dirty you should check the viewModel in kendo way [sample](https://dojo.telerik.com/APiVoMEl/9).

basically I've created a viewModel which is impements the ObservableObject interface and has a two way binding with the form's container.
Every time you change something in the form the change event is fired in the viewModel which set a variable (dirty) as true.

```
var dirty = false;
var viewModel = new kendo.data.ObservableObject({
    fullname: "test"
});
viewModel.bind("change", function () {
    alert("changed");
    dirty = true;
});
kendo.bind($("#tickets"), viewModel);
```

Add all the fields you need to "watch" in the ObservableObject
and set on their markup the property `data-bind="value:fieldName"`

Comment: Thank you but i did not want this answer i have already checked with  this concept

Answer (score 2):

You could use JQuery something like this...

```
var _isDirty = false;
$("input[type='text']").change(function(){
  _isDirty = true;
});
```

Comment: can you please provide any sample based on this

Answer (score 2):

Forms have an `input` event which acts for all child elements. So you can do:

```js
document.querySelector('#my-form')
  .addEventListener('input', () => {
    // now you know that *something* changed inside
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a global boolean variable to remember when you edit anything in your form.

This variable should initially be false, then when the user edits an input, it changes to true. When you submit the form it changes back to false. Now you can check any time you want, whether the dirty variable is true or false.

Example code:

```
var dirty = false;

var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
for (var i = 0;i < inputs.length)
{
    var input = inputs[i];
    input .addEventListener('input', function()
    {
        dirty = true;
    });
}

var form = document.forms[0];
form.addEventListener('submit, function()
{
    dirty = false;
}
```